# How to wait for particular response data that is intercepted in cypress tests

Tags: cypress

I have a complex calculation service on a page that gets triggered on the click of a 'CALCULATE' button. This will trigger the service which will take between 10-30 seconds, so a GET request will be made for every 2 seconds unless the response contains "calculatedRoute" data in the JSON response. I then have to validate the UI against the *calculatedRoute* data

So far, I have the following test in Cypress

```
  cy.intercept("GET", "/v1/calculations/*").as("route-calculations")
  cy.get('#calc').click();
  cy.waitForCalculationRequest('@route-calculations', 30)
```

And in Commands,

```
Cypress.Commands.add("waitForCalculationRequest", (aliasName, retries) => {
  cy.wait(aliasName).its('response.body').then(json => {
    cy.log(typeof json)
    cy.log(json);
    cy.log(json.calculatedRoute);
    if (json.calculatedRoute == "") {
      return
    } 
    else if (retries > 0) {
      cy.waitForCalculationRequest(aliasName, retries - 1);
    } 
  });
});
```

But I am not able to make the command working as it throws

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

GET Response data when the calculation is in progress (all requests except last one):

```
{
  "id": 8,
  "createdAt": "2021-07-13T11:39:11.756095Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-07-13T11:39:11.756095Z",
  "status": "pending",
}
```

GET Response data when the calculation is completed (Last request):

```
{
  "id": 8,
  "createdAt": "2021-07-13T11:39:11.756095Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-07-13T11:39:41.394267Z",
  "status": "complete",
   "calculatedRoute": {
    "route": "bla bla bla",
    "subscriptions": [
      x,y,z
    ],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are almost there, but `json.calculatedRoute` is empty on request #33 and has an object on request #34, so is it just the if() statement, sort of what @ocyoplus says in comments but a bit stronger

```js
if (typeof json.calculatedRoute === 'object') {    // found
  return json.calculatedRoute.route
} 
else if (retries > 0) {
  cy.waitForCalculationRequest(aliasName, retries - 1);
}
```

Alternatively

```js
if (json.status === 'complete') {    // found
  return json.calculatedRoute.route
} 
else if (retries > 0) {
  cy.waitForCalculationRequest(aliasName, retries - 1);
} else {
  // fail the test
  throw 'Status "complete" never occurred'  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you detail in your answer how to read the data from that object? I expect it to be a JSON but it returns an object.

Comment: An object is JSON (or vice-versa). I'm not sure what you are looking for. Do you just need to `return json.calculatedRoute`? I guess you're looking for the bit where you show `{ "route": "bla bla bla" }`?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I want to read `{ "route": "bla bla bla" }` in order to validate the UI

Comment: Since you have `"status": "complete"` on the final response, that might be a better check, i.e `if (json.status === 'complete') { return json.calculatedRoute.route } else ...`

Comment: I was thinking also another `else` to handle failure when retries = 0.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this reccurency could work but it looks like you forget about `cy.` before `waitForCalculationRequest(aliasName, retries - 1);` So it should look like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("waitForCalculationRequest", (aliasName, retries) => {
  cy.wait(aliasName).its('response.body').then(json => {
    if (json.calculatedRoute == "") {
      return
    } 
    else if (retries > 0) {
      cy.waitForCalculationRequest(aliasName, retries - 1);
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed updating that one, updated my question.

Comment: ok, another thing I am thinking about is this fragment  `if (json.calculatedRoute == "")`. If you want to check if json.calculatedRouse exists, this should look maybe like this `if (json.calculatedRoute !== null")` or that `if (json.calculatedRoute !== undefined )`